# ¿Es posible iterar la secuencia de un for en Python con una sola línea sin usar for anidados?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Mientras enseñaba el ciclo for en Python a unos compañeros uno de ellos comentó si era posible iterar las secuencias del ciclo en una misma línea y no dentro de un ciclo, es decir, considere el siguiente for:

```
for i in range (1,5):
    for j in range (1,5,i)
         print(j)
```

Es claro ver que imprime los números del 1 al 4 con las secuencias 1,2,3 y 4.

¿Esto es posible en una misma línea sin la necesidad de usar un for anidado?

En algún momento pensé: `for i in range (Inicio,Fin,i)`

Pero esto es un error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ¿Es posible?

Sí.

### ¿Cómo?

Si no quieres usar un `for` anidado, puedes usar un único `for` que itera sobre la secuencia de rangos y usar `map()` para imprimir cada elemento del rango es cuestión. Es decir:

```
for i in ([range(1,5)] * 4):
    list(map(print,i))
```

- Se genera una lista que contiene cuatro rangos del 1 al 5.
- Se usa `map()` para imprimir cada elemento cada rango (`i`)

*Nota:* Se tiene que castear con `list()` para forzar que todos los elementos del rango se procesen.

Dicho esto, si quieres **hacerlo en una linea**, puedes eleborar una expresión más difícil de leer.

```
list(map(lambda x: list(map(print,x)),[list(range(1,5)) * 4]))
```

Aquí se usa el mismo truco de `map()`, pero dos veces. En esencia es lo mismo que el ejemplo anterior, generas una lista de rangos e iteras sobre cada elemento de cada rango.

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta. El código del OP produce los valores `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1`, mientras que el tuyo da `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4`. Debe haber un error en alguna parte.

Answer (score 1):

Los `for` se pueden agrupar en una sola línea.

Si tienes

```
for i in range (1,5):
    for j in range (1,5,i):
         print(j)
```

que produce la secuencia `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1`, simplemente los *aplanas*, escribiendolos de corrido en el mismo orden del `for` anidado:

```
[print(j) for i in range(1,5) for j in range(1,5, i) ]
```

Esta solución produce la misma secuencia del OP: `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1`.

**Cuerpo complejo**

Si el cuerpo del `for` es más complicado, define una función y llamala para ejecutar el cálculo.

Ejemplo

```
for i in range (1,5):
    for j in range (1,5,i):
         a = i / j
         print(a)
```

Se transforma en

```
def fcn(i, j):
    a = i / j
    print(a)

[fcn(i, j) for i in range(1,5) for j in range(1,5, i)]
```

Comment: +1 pero siendo puristas la solución correcta sería `print("\n".join(str(j) for i in range(1,5) for j in range(1,5,i)))` que evita crear la lista y además no usa `print()`  dentro de la comprensión, pues tu solución creaba una lista de Nones al ser esos los valores retornados por cada `print()`. No me gusta usar comprensiones de listas sólo por sus efectos secundarios (el print) sino solo cuando realmente se quiere crear una lista con los elementos generados.

Comment: @abulafia. Concuerdo contigo. Mi preferencia personal va por los `for` anidados, pues son más versátiles y legibles que la comprensión de listas. Aun con los inconvenientes señalados, es más simple, legible (y correcta) que otras soluciones propuestas.